# "Incompatible types" when accessing Map#entrySet()

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on a simple config file reader for fun, but I am getting an odd error while writing the test method. In it is a `for` loop, and I have made sure that it causes the problem. It gives me this compilation error:

```
Incompatible types:
    Required: java.util.Map.Entry
    Found: java.lang.Object
```

The Map declaration is this:

```
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

The `for` loop is written as below:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : props.entrySet()) {
    //Body
}
```

An SSCCE without imports which demonstrates the problem (At least in IntelliJ):

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            props.put(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32), new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : props.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

`map` is a `Map<String, String>`, so that can't be the problem. I have googled alternative methods of doing this, but the main one people use seems to be this one! Yet for some reason it still fails. Any help would be appreciated. If you offer an alternative solution, please make sure it is fast - these config files could potentially be huge.

Comment: Done. I doubt that it changes anything to be defined as a HashMap.

Comment: This code doesn't produce any errors. You must be leaving something out.

Comment: It seems like your IntelliJ is broken, or you're losing the generics information of props somewhere in your code, or you're not looking at the right "props" variable.

Comment: @Keppil I am leaving nothing out that doesn't produce errors. With literally *nothing* but those two lines, it still gives me an error.

Comment: @Kayaman Could it be that the wrong Map is imported or something?

Comment: @NickHartley No, the error message clearly implies that props.entrySet() is returning a Set without generics information. Which means that the map has been constructed without generics information (or it has been lost somewhere on the way).

Comment: Can you give us a short complete program ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) that produces the error?

Comment: @Keppil Sure, give me a moment to write it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of what you may be doing - it is difficult to be sure without more code.

```
class ATest<T> {
  Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();

  void aTest() {
    // Works fine.
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : props.entrySet()) {
    }
  }

  void bTest() {
    ATest aTest = new ATest();
    // ERROR! incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Entry<String,String>
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : aTest.props.entrySet()) {
    }
  }

  void cTest(Map props) {
    // ERROR! incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Entry<String,String>
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : props.entrySet()) {
    }
  }

}
```

Notice that in `bTest` I create an `ATest` without its generic type parameter. In that situation Java removes **all** generic information from the class, including, as you will see, the `<String,String>` from the `props` variable inside it.

Alternatively - you may be accidentally removing the generic nature of the properties map - like I demonstrate in `cTest`.

Comment: Since yours is the one with an actual potential solution, I'll accept it, even though the problem was something else entirely. I hope it helps others.

Comment: Wow, just when I thought Java generics couldn't be weirder than they already are, thanks

Comment: That's really stupid. Java should know it is a `Set<Entry>` but it even drops the info about Entry when a non related generic is missing

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare your map as a HashMap.

`HashMap<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();`

This is what solved my problem.